# Angularjs redirect with search parameters

Tags: angularjs

I use angularjs 1.6 on my routes I have the following

```
  when('/myview', {
    templateUrl: 'mc/templates/myview.html',
    controller: 'myviewController'
  }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/defaultView'
  });
```

When I access myview with search parameters it loads the myview view

```
/myview?foo=bar
```

When I try to redirect to this view though

```
$location.path(' /myview?foo=bar');
```

Does not work and loads the defaultView

How can I redirect on a view with search parameters ?

Comment: use this `templateUrl: 'mc/templates/myview.html/:foo',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
 $state.go("myview", { foo: 'bar' });
```

or with location use .search

```
$location.path('/myview').search('foo', 'bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$location.path('/myview').search('foo', 'bar')
```